# How to change a key in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How is it possible to change a key in SharedPreferences? Suppose I wanted to implement a Bookmarks class using SharedPreferences. When the user wants to rename a bookmark, there should be a way to change the corresponding key to the new name. What is the way to do that?

I tried keeping the value of the entry in an `Object` variable, removing the entry and then creating a new one with the new name and the value of the variable, but that doesn't work out since there is no `get()` function in SharedPreferences that returns an `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

- First get old key-value
- Then clear your old key
- Finally put your newKey-oldValue.

Comment: I may be wrong but that sounds very similar to what I already said in the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: As I know,you can't store a `Object` directly.

Comment: @MohammadSanei: `SharedPreferences` does not hold arbitrary objects. As a result, you do not need a "`get()` function in `SharedPreferences` that returns an `Object`". You use the `get...()` function that returns whatever the data type is that you put in the `SharedPreferences` under this key in the first place. In general, IMHO, `SharedPreferences` is not a great option for this sort of data model. I recommend using something else (SQLite, a `JSON` file, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare Please move your comment to the answers so that I have at least one proper answer. Thanks :)